# HttpClient behaviour for persistent/continuous connections

Tags: dart

I'm trying to use the CouchDB change notifications API in continuous mode, so I want send this
_changes?feed=continuous?include_docs=true to my CouchDb server as a GET request. Easy so far, but to get HttpClient to send it I have to do this :-

```
_changesClient.openUrl('GET', uri)
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) {

        return request.close();
      })
```

This closes the connection which I don't want, I want to send the request and then just sit listening for incoming data i.e the changes that CouchDB is emitting. I can't seem to fathom this, it seems that HttpClient is geared towards a single shot send/receive model or I'v missed something.

Comment: For other readers, there's a bug with some discussion here: http://dartbug.com/14949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK resolved, see the bug link above for the outcome